# How can I generate input / output tuples in SML?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml, caml, ml

I am working on a project in SML where I need to write a function that takes as input a function and an integer. This function needs to generate a list of input / output tuples for the given function that is passed into it. For example, if I call the function like this:

```
finiteListRepresentation(square, 5);
```

where:

```
fun square(x) = x*x
```

The function needs to return the list of tuples:

```
[(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)]
```

Obviously the square function can be any function such as an integer cube function or something like that. The problem I am having is getting the function to recursively "visit" each integer starting from the specified value. I am very new to SML and I can get the function to return a single value such as:

```
finiteListRepresenation(f, x) = [(x, f(x))]
```

Can somebody help me as to how can I generalize this function to calculate every value starting from 1 until the it reaches the specified integer?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are looking for hints more than a solution, check out the [`map` function](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.map:VAL) and try to figure out how it could help:

```
val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

> ```
> map f l
> ```
>
> applies `f` to each element of `l` from left to right, returning the list of results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess my main problem is recursively enumerating numbers in SML. For example, if I want to make a function that takes a single integer and generates a list from 1 to that integer, how would I go about doing this recursively?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am having is getting the function to recursively "visit" each integer starting from the specified value.

Try writing a helper function `range : int * int -> int list` which enumerates the integers between a lower and upper bound. For example,

```
val [2,3,4,5,6,7] = range (2, 7)
```

To get started, consider implementing `range` recursively in terms of itself. Here's a hint:

```
(* assume i <= j *)
fun range (i, j) =
  if i = j then (* TODO *)
  else i :: (* TODO *)
```

Once you have this function, `finiteListRepresentation` should be very straightforward with a [List.map](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.map:VAL).